# How to replace Array key in explode

Tags: php, laravel

I have code like bellow

```
$string = "Trainee,Beginner";
```

I want to replace the $string to array object with explode

```
$list = explode(',', $string);
```

The result I got.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => "Trainee"
  1 => "Beginner"
];
```

The result I want.

```
array:2 [▼
  'Trainee' => "Trainee"
  'Beginner' => "Beginner"
];
```

Comment: Explain your output little bit more.Its confusing/misleading.

Comment: what do you mean by "i want between key and val equal" ?

Comment: Add your expected output to your question.

Comment: not clear ,pls edit

Comment: i'm sorry my english is not good, i just want to replace array object key same with array value. but the issue has been clear. @Always Sunny very helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `array_combine()` that takes one array as key and another as value. So just pass the `$list` for both parameters and you're good to go.

```
<?php
$string = "Trainee,Beginner";
$list = explode(',', $string);
$final_array = array_combine($list, $list);
print_r($final_array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/vmgaH

Answer (score 0):

You can try using **`foreach loop`**

```
<?php
$string = "Trainee,Beginner";

$list = explode(',', $string);


foreach($list as $item){
    echo $item.'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
Trainee
Beginner
```

Comment: i do not want to looping, i just want the output like this                                                               array:2 [▼
  'Trainee' => "Trainee"
  'Beginner' => "Beginner"
];

Answer (score 0):

With Laravel you could just use the `collect` method.

`$list = collect(explode(',', $string))->keyBy(function ($item) { return $item; });`